# New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment Command not recognizing the JSON paramaters file

Tags: powershell, azure

I have a JSON parameters file that looks like this.

```
"parameters": {
        "field_1": {
            "value": "abc"
        },
        "field_2": {
            "value": 123
        },
```

and I am using the below command to create resources in Azure

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -TemplateFile $templateFilePath -TemplateParameterFile $parametersFilePath
```

when I run it, for some reason it's not recognizing the parameters that are in the parameters file. It asks me to enter the parameters individually in powershell and then after I enter all of them I get the below error:

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 4:07:58 PM - Error: Code=InvalidDeploymentParameterValue; Message=The value of deployment parameter 'parameters' is null. Please specify the value or use the parameter reference. See 
https://aka.ms/arm-deploy/#parameter-file for details.
At line:52 char:4

```
+    New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGro ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to share the template & param json?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it should not recognize it, if you look at the Azure Quickstart templates repository, most of those have parameter files, all of them have a proper structure, while yours don't, here's how a proper parameter file looks like:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "adminUsername": {
        "value": "ghuser"
        },
        "adminPassword": {
        "value": "GEN-PASSWORD"
        },
        "dnsLabelPrefix": {
        "value": "GEN-UNIQUE"
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates